# Extract value from PHP JSON object into jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm dynamically generating a list of values in PHP which I've converted into json using json_encode as below:

```
<?php $posts = get_post_meta(get_the_id(), 'size_repeatable', false);
    $specials = array();
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $size_available = $post['size_available'];
        if(intval(get_the_title($size_available)) > 1) { $add_sq_ft = " sq ft room"; } else { $add_sq_ft = ""; }
        $size_special_offer = $post['size_special_offer'];
        $specials[] = array(get_the_title($size_available) . $add_sq_ft => $post['size_special_offer']);
    }
    $specials_simplified = array_reduce($specials, 'array_merge', array());
    $specials_json = json_encode($specials_simplified);
?>
```

Which produces this JSON:

```
{"15 sq ft room":"10% off your first month","25 sq ft room":"15% off your first 1 month","35 sq ft room":"20% off your first 1 month","50 sq ft room":"25% off your first 1 month","75 sq ft room":"50% off your first 2 month","100 sq ft room":"50% off your first 2 month","125 sq ft room":"50% off your first 2 month","150 sq ft room":"50% off your first 2 months","200 sq ft room":"50% off your first 2 month"}
```

I then have a standard HTML Select field which has 15 sq ft room, 25 sq ft room, 35 sq ft room, 50 sq ft room, 75 sq ft room etc as selectable Option items (you can only select one option at a time).

I've then got a .change jQuery function, which when changed should refer to the JSON values above e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('#input_2_11').change(function(event) {
            var current_selection = $('#input_2_11' + ' option:selected').html();
            var size_json = <?php echo $specials_json; ?>;
            $('#dynamic_offer').html(size_json);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Basically I need to compare the #input_2_11 label with the JSON object, to display the correct value (special offer).

For instance, if a user had selected "15 sq ft room" then it would display "10% off your first month" in the #dynamic_offer div.

But this is where I'm really struggling - firstly trying to compare the variables 'current_selection' with 'size_json' and then displaying the correct special offer associated with that size.

Comment: you could just render the dropdown from json response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAybe you can try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#input_2_11').change(function(event) {
        var current_selection = $('#input_2_11' + ' option:selected').html();
        var size_json = <?php echo $specials_json; ?>[current_selection];
        $('#dynamic_offer').html(size_json);
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand how that would compare the two variables and also return the correct special offer from the JSON? Any ideas?

Comment: because you have an json in php and you printed in the variable size_json, when you put size_json["somekey"] it return you the result of the key in this case "somekey" are the value of the current_selection var

Comment: @user9099702 the extra `current_selection` in brackets means 'return the value whose key is equal to `current_selection` from the JSON data'.

Comment: @JassonRojas this method may work, but for code clarity it's probably better to store the whole PHP output as `size_json` and then access the needed key later, rather than all at once like your example.

Comment: @DavidMillar Thats rigth, in case of the key does not exist it return undefined

Comment: Yeah nice - I've just checked this out and it does indeed work. Let me just double double check and then I'll mark this as the solution :-) Thanks v. much - I was almost there!!! :-)

Comment: Thanks @DavidMillar for the clarification :) !

Answer (score 0):

Have you used console.log() to inspect what `current_selection` contains and to verify the contents of `size_json`?

I think `current_selection` won't be quite what you've expected; `.html()` will return the entire HTML inside the option whereas you likely want to try something like `$('#input_2_11').val()` to get the current value of the input.

Once you have the value in `current_selection`, you can do `size_json[current_selection]` to access the special offer, since the value in `current_selection` will be the key of the key-value pair you need from `size_json`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var size_json = <?php echo $specials_json; ?>;
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $('#input_2_11').change(function() {
            // If you need the option's value
            //var current_selection = $('#input_2_11').val();

            // If you just want the text of the option.
            var current_selection = $('#input_2_11 option:selected').html();

            $('#dynamic_offer').html(size_json[current_selection]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no the value has to be the price (integer), so I can't compare that unfortunately. But the answer above looks like it works (which is similar to yours. Thanks v. much :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully working example. Use `.html()` of an option as a key inside `json` variable. To make your code work simply replace assignment to `json` with `<?php echo $specials_json; ?>;`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // For brevity
  var size_json = {"15 sq ft room":"10% off your first month","25 sq ft room":"15% off your first 1 month","35 sq ft room":"20% off your first 1 month","50 sq ft room":"25% off your first 1 month","75 sq ft room":"50% off your first 2 month","100 sq ft room":"50% off your first 2 month","125 sq ft room":"50% off your first 2 month","150 sq ft room":"50% off your first 2 months","200 sq ft room":"50% off your first 2 month"};

  // You don't need this part.
  for (var key in size_json) {
    if (size_json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      $('#input_2_11').append($('<option/>').html(key));
    }
  }

  function checkSelection() {
    var current_selection = $('#input_2_11 option:selected').html();
    $('#dynamic_offer').html(size_json[current_selection]); // Note the [current_selection]
  }
  checkSelection();

  $('#input_2_11').change(checkSelection);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="input_2_11">

</select>

<div id="dynamic_offer">

</div>
```